# Rx.net and The Actor Model

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have a situation where I need to return an `IObservable<T>` from a method. It is to return a new value of object `T` Whenever it has changed.

The trigger that the object has changed will come from the actor system, in my example we are using [Proto.Actor](http://proto.actor/).

I have gotten an example to "work", however I feel it is not correctly implementing `IObservable` and will not allow for proper unsubscription etc.

My solution:

```cs
    public IObservable<T> Watch<T>(long id)
    {
        var subscriber = _actorFactory.GetActor<ObjectChangedActor>();
        var request = new ObjectWatchRequest(id);

        return Observable.Create<T>(async (observer, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var response = await subscriber.RequestAsync<ObjectUpdatedResponse>(request, cancellationToken);
                    // once it gets past the above line, we have gotten notice that the object has been updated
                    var updatedObj = await Get<T>(id);
                    observer.OnNext(updatedObj);
                }
            }, cancellationToken);

            // will this ever be called?
            return Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disposal called");
            });
        });
    }
```

I feel like, despite the fact it "works" in that all updates are pushed to the subscriber, it will never be able to accurately dispose, and I don't feel like `while (true)` should ever be put in code, even when it is on a separate thread.

How would I best handle a list of messages coming back from the actor system and turning those into an `IObservable` that the user can dispose of (unsubscribe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided a full working example of your code, which has made it difficult to give you a working solution that you can just copy and paste. However, I've made a cut-down version that I think you can probably work from.

You're right that your solution is not a good implementation.

Here's a basic version of your code that should work about right once you put your objects in:

```
public IObservable<T> Watch<T>(long id)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Defer(() =>
                from x in Observable.FromAsync(() => RequestAsync())
                from y in Observable.FromAsync(() => Get<T>(id))
                select y)
            .Repeat();
}
```

Let me know if this hits the mark for you.

Comment: Yes, indeed it hits the mark for me. I had already made use of `.Repeat()` in an updated solution but I was not using `Observable.Defer`. Still not 100% on how that differs from `Observable.Create` but I will do some further reading.